# thread safe shared library called from Progress 9.1d

Tags: concurrency, shared-libraries, progress-4gl

I'm working on a project that involves legacy systems written in Progress 9.1d. These systems need to use a shared library I programmed in C language.

I was told by the Progress folks that the aplication works via something called an "appserver". This appserver has something they call "agents" and when a user executes the Progress application, the appserver instantiates (I suppose it´s called that way) an agent to attend the petition. There are a limited number of agents and when the limit is surpassed, the petitions are queued.

So, each of these agents executes the Progress code that uses my shared library. My fear is that there could be data collisions between them. The shared library does not has global nor static variables. All the data the shared library function uses is created inside it, all variables are local.

The shared library and the Progress appserver are in a same UNIX server HP-UX 11.1

I'm guessing that each new agent has it's own copy of the data of the Progress aplication, but if it does, I don't know if the same happens with the shared library stuff...

If someone has expereince using shared libraries with Progress, are there some measures to take for concurrency?

So far our tests have been without problems.

Any comment would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Wow, welcome to the stone ages!  :)  On a serious note, you said that your shared library doesn't have any components that are shared between methods, so what are you concerned about colliding?  It sounds like you're good.  Also, to answer your question about the appserver: The code is cached by the application, not the appserver itself (which is just a middleman of sorts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app server instance is an individual UNIX process.  So your worries about shared data shouldn't come up.

Shared libraries can work and can be called by Progress, even on such an ancient and obsolete release as 9.1D -- but Progress is aggressively single-threaded so if your shared lib uses threads in any way it may fail.

Who is responsible for calling the shared library from the 4GL code?  You? Or the Progress developers?  In either case this might be helpful:

http://dbappraise.com/ppt/shlib.pptx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Progress developers are responsible, I'll share with them your document. :)

No, fortunately the shared lib doesn't use threads.

When you said "Each app server instance" those are the so called agents, right?

Comment: That is correct.  An agent is its own process -- usually you will see it in "ps" as _proapsv (that's the default executable -- some vendors rename it for various reasons).

Comment: Data type mapping and callbacks are the other two "gotchyas".  Simple data types (int, float, string) are fine.  Structs and pointers might be trouble (not always impossible but might be a challenge).  Callbacks probably won't work at all.